# How to use teamcity for android application deployment

Tags: gradle, teamcity, android-gradle-plugin

How can i sue TeamCity for android application deployment.

Currently i am trying to use **Gradle** for this and not getting any success.

Is there any other way or any other build runner in TeamCity for android applications deployment ?

Comment: Where do you want to deploy your app to? eg: hockeyapp

Comment: @NevinRajVictor   Sorry for late reply. This teamcity deployment is going on our own server.
Once this build gets successful, I am going to create Build Artifact and will download it from there only.

Comment: . Change directory to to where your main gradle file is present in terminal. Try to execute `gradlew clean build` command . If this command generates the apk in your build folder Add a command line build step in teamcity with the above steps.